# Set background image in ionic 5

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, background-image

I want to set an image as a background theme in the ionic 5 React app

I have tried

```
--background: url(../assets/GettyImages-129287.jpg) no-repeat cover fixed;
.ion-page,#root,body,ion-content,#background-content {background: url(../assets/GettyImages-129287.jpg);}
```

but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 4):

I think It should look like as in Ionic Angular version:

```
ion-content {
    --background: url(/assets/bg.jpeg);
}
```

Comment: i need for react version

Comment: @HemantRajpoot Did you try to add it to the global styles? I suppose React project should have global styles as Angular.

Comment: yes I have tried but ionpage has bgcolor white which overlapping the base bg can you try with angular and send me code?

Comment: @HemantRajpoot I checked in my own project and updated the answer. This code works for me for the Angular project.

Comment: can you tell me how to background property cover?

Comment: @HemantRajpoot It's complicated a little bit. I see that real background is part of shadow dom and we should update styles for it. In Angular I can use `::ng-deep` or something but I don't know how It works in React.